# Trying to get the ID of <td id="idHere"> id in c# (Windows Forms)

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, browser, getelementbyid

```
<td id="idHere">
<a href="javascript:">Button</a> </td>
```

Super simple question, but I'm a noob. I'm trying to get the ID of a button (in this case "idHere") and then click it. Using this:

```
webBrowser.Document.GetElementById("idHere").InvokeMember("Click");
```

Doesn't work. How can I get this id in C#?

I've seen questions like this before but the answers were complicated and I couldn't understand.

Sorry if this is a common question and thanks in advance!

Comment: you're tring to invoke the click on the `td` itself. You need to take the element returned by the GetElementById, and search for the `<a>` below that, THEN invoke the click on that.

Comment: @Marc, thanks for your answer! But how would I go about doing that? Again, I'm sort of a noob.

Comment: no idea. I've never worked with c#. I'd be surprised if it didn't have some relatively "standard"-ish DOM-type operations for "find an element, then search below it" stuff.

Comment: `id` stands for `identity` which is used to access/reference back to something, so if there was some way you could use to access your `button`, why do you need its `id`? I mean `id` must be something you know beforehand. If not, you have to find something special on what you are finding to treat it as `id` (although it's not actually).

Answer (score 0):

As @MarcB pointed out, `.Document.GetElementById("idHere")` will get the `<td>` element, not the `<a>` element. If you want the `<a>` you will need something like:

```
var a = webBrowser.Document.GetElementById("idHere").FirstChild;
```

You haven't shown us the content of your `href` attribute, but assuming it is safe to click it, you can call:

```
a.InvokeMember("Click");
```